# How can an Android push notification sent from Azure get to 'Enqueued' but not get received on the phone?

Tags: android, azure, push-notification

How can this happen? I am getting reports that people aren't getting notifications, but my logs show Azure gave back 'Enqueued'. I can't recreate it; I get the notification but not everyone does. I don't have access to any of their phones.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should know how the notification hub works.

[image]

> In a typical send notification flow, the message is sent from the application backend to Azure Notification Hub (NH) which in turn does some processing on all the registrations taking into account the configured tags & tag expressions to determine "targets" i.e. all the registrations that need to receive the push notification. These registrations can span across any or all of our supported platforms - iOS, Google, Windows, Windows Phone, Kindle and Baidu for China Android. Once the targets are established, NH then pushes out notifications, split across multiple batch of registrations, to the device platform specific Push Notification Service (PNS) - e.g. APNS for Apple, GCM for Google etc. NH authenticates with the respective PNS based on the credentials you set in the Azure Classic Portal on the Configure Notification Hub page. The PNS then forwards the notifications to the respective client devices.

So if the  notification message has been received by the respective PNS then it is its responsibility to deliver the notification to the device.

Azure Notification Hubs is out of the picture here and has no control on when or if the notification is going to be delivered to the device.

The platform notification service will continue working to send the message to the device.

**You will just see the azure NH gave back 'Enqueued'.**

So I suggest you could try to use google play console(Need associate with the FCM app you have set in the azure notification hub). Then you could view FCM statistics.

More details about how to view FCM statistics, you could refer to this [article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en).

Comment: The ones that were enqueued but the customer didn't get them don't show up when I put the registration token on the Play console. The ones that they did get do show up. Why were they enqueued but didn't get to FCM?

Comment: You have checked the FCM, the NH shows it is already enqueued. but the FCM doesn't get it?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happens.